# What will be the Criteria for following SQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-criteria

Can any one help me out with Criteria for following query :

```
SELECT * From TableA Inner Join TableB On TableA.ID=TableB.ID
```

I am trying with the following Criteria

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TableA.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("TableB", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

The above criteria retrives both the table data.

Also if I need only specific columns from TableA how will the criteria Change ?

Thanks for your time.

Edit: TableA has one-to-many relationship with TableB.

Comment: Did you any answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question doesn't make sense. In hibernate, the 2 Tables should actually be entities in which case they would have a relationship between them. Are you trying to randomly join 2 tables and get a result back? If so you have to use sql and use a `ResultTransformer` to convert the result into objects.

```
private ResultTransformer getResultsTransformer()
{
    ResultTransformer transformer = new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(
            MyResultBean.class) {
        @Override
        public Object transformTuple(Object[] values, String[] aliases)
        {
            MyResultBean row = new MyResultBean();
            for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++)
            {
                row.set(aliases[i], values[i]);
            }
            return (row);
        }
    };
    return transformer;
}
```

Call this as follows:

```
    Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    q.setResultTransformer(getResultsTransformer());
    List<MyResultBean> list = q.list();
```

**UPDATE**: If Table A has a 1-to-Many with Table B, then I find it easiest to use Alias

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(TableA.class);
criteria.createAlias("tableB","b");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("id", "b.id");
criteria.list();
```

I hope this helps. Regards,

Comment: Sorry editted the question, there is one to many relationship form TableA to TableB.

Comment: @Ritesh, answer has been updated. It's not tested but should give you the general idea of what you have to do.

Comment: Yes your approach works, just edited addAlias to createAlias. But the one which I used is Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(TableAlass).createCriteria("tableB");  criteria.list(); This worked fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

With `JOIN`, you need to indicate to Hibernate that you only want the "root entity", whcih is tableA.  Add the following to your code:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```